# Sandbox architecture in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, architecture, sandbox

Is it possible to develop a web-app in ASP.NET (framework is not a constraint), to have a sandbox architecture, and deploy widgets without disturbing the parent application?

I expect both the parent application and the widget to be developed using .NET.

EDIT:
To elaborate, I want to have an web-app, say App1, and widgets (say wid1 and wid2). wid1 and wid2 should be like a plugin into App1, only difference is that, if I make any changes to wid1, I want to be able to deploy it without disturbing App1 or Wid2.
The widgets can be something similar to a flash object, only that it needs to be developed on .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/) be what you are looking for?  They even have a WebForms sample:- http://mef.codeplex.com/releases/view/44166

Comment: Gee thanks.. This looks promising, but still in development stage, need to check with my architect if we can start prototypes using this. +1 to you!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you will want to look into Application Pools.
In a web server running IIS with ASP.NET websites, you can create Application Pools which will contain your applications (web sites). You can restrict pools to limit resources usage like RAM, CPU, # of threads, etc. If one of the websites go crazy, it should only affect it's own Application Pool. You can put more than one website in a single Application Pool so if you put all of the websites in one Application Pool, then they will all crash together.

Comment: @StevenGilligan: I guess, I wasn't clear in my question. I am not looking at the App Pool aspect. Have updated the question with some elaboration.